# BulkOperations upsert throwing Invalid BSON field name

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Here is my java code

```
public void upsertAll(final List<StringEntry> strings) {
    BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, StringEntry.class, DOCUMENT);
    List<Pair<Query, Update>> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.forEach(string -> {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("msgid").is(string.getMsgId()));  
        Document doc = new Document();
        mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(string, doc);
        Update update = Update.fromDocument(doc); 
        bulkOps.upsert(query, update);
    }); 
    bulkOps.execute();
}
```

Exception from stacktrace.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name msgid
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:534)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterDecorator.writeName(BsonWriterDecorator.java:193)
        at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:211)
        at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:154)
        at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SplittablePayload$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(SplittablePayload.java:221)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SplittablePayload$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(SplittablePayload.java:187)
```

How can I get the bulk upsert function to work?

Comment: What does documentation say is the correct usage?

Comment: I couldn’t find any documentation on usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source code and tests of the library, I have managed to solve my problem. [BulkOperationsIntegrationTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/91c39e2825076d7bc2394f62830caa84b065a41e/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/DefaultBulkOperationsIntegrationTests.java)

```
public void upsertAll(final List<StringEntry> strings) {
    FindAndReplaceOptions options = FindAndReplaceOptions.options();
    BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, StringEntry.class, DOCUMENT);
    List<Pair<Query, Update>> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    for(StringEntry string: strings) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("msgid").is(string.getMsgId()));  
        Document doc = new Document();
        mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(string, doc);
        bulkOps = bulkOps.replaceOne(query, doc, options.upsert()); 
    }
    bulkOps.execute();
}
```

It seems that the `upsert` function is not really working as intended. Replacing it with `replaceOne` worked.